# Maximizar y restaurar la ventana

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("23.ui",self)
        self.s = 0

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.bmax.clicked.connect(self.W_Size)
        self.bmin.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.bclose.clicked.connect(self.close)



    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

    def W_Size(self):

        if self.s == 0:
            self.showMaximized()
            self.s=1

        elif self.s==1:
            self.s = 0
            self.resize(878,575)    
            qRect = self.frameGeometry()
            centerPoint  = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
            qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
            self.move(qRect.topLeft())


app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

En el cual la variable **s** se encarga de manipular la acción que tomara el evento del boton **self.bmax**.

La idea es que al oprimir el boton **self.bmax**, compare si el valor de la variable = 0 entonces al oprimir el botón la ventana se mostrara en pantalla completa y cambiara el valor de s ahora "s=1"; para que al oprimir nuevamente el botón ahora cambie el tamaño de la ventana y la posicione al centro.
Nuevamente s retoma el valor de "0", para repetir todo el proceso,

pero es en esta ultima parte donde ya no funciona el código. Ya que no realiza de nuevo la acción de mostrar la ventana en pantalla completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es la variable `s`, sino que cuando maximizas la ventana esta cambia de estado, la solucion es restaurarlo a su estado normal con `showNormal()` como muestro a continuacion:

```
def W_Size(self):
    if self.s == 0:
        self.showMaximized()
        self.s=1
    elif self.s==1:
        self.s = 0
        self.showNormal()
        self.resize(878, 575) 
        qRect = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint  = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qRect.topLeft())
```

---

Aunque una forma más elegante seria evitar crear ese flag y usar el metodo `isMaximized()`.

```
def W_Size(self):
    if self.isMaximized():
        self.showNormal()
        self.resize(878, 575) 
        qRect = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint  = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qRect.topLeft())
    else:
        self.showMaximized()
```

Comment: @ellyanesc gracias la funcion isMaximized. Es la q andava buscando

Comment: @Revsky01 te recomiendo leer la documentacion :)